# Reorder matrix rows and columns simultaneously by a group variable

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, matrix

Consider the data "df" below with group variable "g". I am trying to find a way to sort the data by row and column according to the order of "g".

```
g <- c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
df1 <- c(1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 0.4)
df2 <- c(0.2, 1, 0.7, 0.6, 0.3)
df3 <- c( 0.5, 0.7, 1, 0.4, 0.1) 
df4 <- c(0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 1, 0.9) 
df5 <- c(0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 1) 
df <- data.frame(g, df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
colnames(df) <- c("g", 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
df
```

This is an example from a large data set. Using the sort function in R I performed the task as follows

```
r.df <- df[,sort.list(df[1,])]
s.df <- r.df[sort.list(r.df[,1]),]
```

by ordering the rows first according to g (i.e., first row) and then columns next by g (i.e., first column). However, the second stage distorts the order of the rows. I expect to have something like

```
g 1   1   2   2   2
1 1.0 0.6 0.2 0.7 0.3
1 0.6 1.0 0.8 0.4 0.9
2 0.2 0.8 1.0 0.5 0.4
2 0.7 0.4 0.5 1.0 0.1
2 0.3 0.9 0.4 0.1 1.0
```

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
df[order(df$g), c(1L, order(colnames(df)[-1L]) + 1L)]
#   g   1 1.1   2 2.1 2.2
# 2 1 1.0 0.6 0.2 0.7 0.3
# 4 1 0.6 1.0 0.8 0.4 0.9
# 1 2 0.2 0.8 1.0 0.5 0.4
# 3 2 0.7 0.4 0.5 1.0 0.1
# 5 2 0.3 0.9 0.4 0.1 1.0
```

Note that your column names are invalid, may not be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Function `order` can take more than one vector to order after as an argument. If you `order(v1, v2, v3)`, then it will first order according to `v1` and then resolve ties with `v2`  and so on.

This is how to order after columns `g` and then the first column:

```r
neworder <- order(df$g, df[,2])
df[neworder, ]
# g   2   1   2   1   2
# 2 1 0.2 1.0 0.7 0.6 0.3
# 4 1 0.8 0.6 0.4 1.0 0.9
# 5 2 0.4 0.3 0.1 0.9 1.0
# 3 2 0.5 0.7 1.0 0.4 0.1
# 1 2 1.0 0.2 0.5 0.8 0.4
```

I had to extract the second column as `df[,2]`, because you gave identical column names - not good, see @jay.sf's answer.

To order after all columns, you can create a list of all column vectors and use `do.call` to use that list as arguments of function `order`:

```r
neworder <- do.call("order", as.list(df))
df[neworder, ]
```